# Using record types in FSYACC

Tags: f#, tuples, grammar, record, fsyacc

In FSYACC it is common to have terminals that result in tuples. However, for convenience I want to use a record type instead. For example, if I have the following in my Abstract Syntax Tree (AbstractSyntaxTree.fsl):

```
namespace FS
module AbstractSyntaxTree =

 type B = { x : int; y : int }

 type Either = 
      | Record of B
      | Tuple of int * string

 type A =
     | Int of int
     | String of string
     | IntTuple of Either
```

I'm not clear on the correct syntax in FSYACC (parser.fsy), because if I use:

```
%start a
%token <string> STRING
%token <System.Int32> INT
%token ATOMTOKEN TUPLETOKEN EOF
%type < A > a

%%

a:
    | atomS { $1 }
    | atomI { $1 }
    | either { $1 }

atomI:
    | ATOMTOKEN INT   { Int($2) }

atomS:
    | ATOMTOKEN STRING { String($2)  }

either:
    | TUPLETOKEN INT INT { Record {x=$2;y=$3} } // !!!
    | TUPLETOKEN TUPLETOKEN INT STRING { Tuple( $3, $4) } // !!!
```

I would expect the type B and the Tuple to be inferred. However, FSYACC gives the error for both of the lines marked with "!!!":

```
This expression was expected to have type  A but here has type Either
```

What is the correct syntax to for the "either" production on the last two lines?

Comment: ok, i got fsyacc now, can you post your fsy?

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel. I've taken the working solution you gave and made it resemble more closely my own code. The discriminated union with a record type is one level deeper, the lines I've commented with exclamation marks are the ones for which I can't work out the syntax.

Comment: Oh, that's easy... You still need to return an `A`, so all you need to do `IntTuple(Record{ x = $2; y = $3 }` and `IntTuple(Tuple( $3, $4))`

Comment: Yes that works perfectly, without adding an extra level. Thanks! Now I need to tidy up the above mess... Do you want to add that to your answer ?

Comment: I extended my answer with an **EDIT 2**. If this works for you, please be as kind as marking it as answered. And don't hesitate to ask further questions, if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you mean `IntTuple($2, $3)` as opposed to `B($2, $3)`? I'd try `IntTuple{x=$2; y=$3}`

**EDIT:** this works:

```
module Ast

type B = { x : int; y : int }
type A =
    | Int of int
    | String of string
    | IntTuple of B
```

and

```
%{

open Ast

%}

%start a
%token <string> STRING
%token <System.Int32> INT
%token ATOMTOKEN TUPLETOKEN 
%type < Ast.A > a


%%

a:
    | atom { $1 }
    | tuple { $1 }

atom:
    | ATOMTOKEN INT   { Int($2) }
    | ATOMTOKEN STRING { String($2) }

tuple:
    | TUPLETOKEN INT INT { IntTuple {x = $2; y = $3} }
```

**EDIT 2:** Take good care, that the line `%type < Ast.A > a` requires your non-terminal `a` to be of type `Ast.A`. So therefore, since you are using the non-terminal `tuple` directly, `tuple` needs to be of type `Ast.A`. As such, you have to wrap the record in `IntTuple`, so the syntax is `IntTuple {x = $2; y = $3}` as opposed to just `{x = $2; y = $3}`.

Comment: Yes you're right about IntTuple, I'll correct that. However, I don't believe your other idea is valid syntax.

Comment: Just a thought; could it be confusing fsyacc that there are two sets of braces? Try making a create function instead of writing the record explicitly. (Sorry don't have fsyacc available atm)